# How to transfer a String object from activity_1 to activity_3 directly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have ***activity1***, ***activity2*** ,***activity3***.
I want to transfer a string from **activity1** to **activity3** directly (don't want to open ***activity3***), but want to open **activity2** at the same time. Please help me with Java code, I am new to android.

Comment: So you want to open activity2 and then from activity2 open activity3? With the string in activity3?

Answer (score 3):

Hi I don't think that'd be directly possible, when starting an activity `new Intent()` that's when you pass a string from activity1 to activity2 with `new Intent().putExtra("tag","some string")`
so you can continue passing the same string from one activity to the other,

or you can opt to store that string in the SharedPreference from activity1 and then access it in any other activity in the application for that use the following code

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("TAG",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("StringTag","Some string");
    editor.apply();
```

to Access that string use

```
SharedPreferences pref =getSharedPreferences("TAG",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myString = pref.getString("StringTag","defaultString");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it,let me break down two of them.

- First Way: Use Intent's `put.Extra()` method.

As correctly @Lloyd pointed out, you can use `Intent put.Extra()` like so:

```java
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityYouWantToGo.class);
i.putExtra("ObjectName","YourValueHere");
startActivity(i);
```

and on the other side you simply do:

```java
String yourStringObject= (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ObjectName");
```

Keep in mind that the `second parameter` of `putExtra()` has to `implement` **Serializable** ,  `String` class does it by default.

- Second way: Make the `fields` you want `static` and get them over with a `static` method.

For instance:

```java
public class  MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static String youStringname = "A Value To Get";

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

  public static String getYourString()
   {
       return youStringname;
   }

}
```

and simply refer to where ever you like like so

`String myString =  MainActivity.getYourString();`

Hope it helps!

Edit: `static` usually caches your values

Comment: Second way suits my condition but my value is not static  (have to take value from override onCreate of main activity)

Comment: @Simarkalsi you can try to make it static and initialize it inside `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you transfer a value from a activity to another when you don't want to open that activity? Then they value become unused I guess.

Look at intents for transferring a string value from one activity to another.

Comment: I will open it later but i cant pass string in activity 2

Comment: Maybe consider using fragments to avoid having a activity 2. It that case you can pass value through interfaces